# Windows 8 Login configuration

Tags: windows, windows-8, login, smartcard

I have a requirement where I use a smart card to login in Windows 8.

(In windows-7, as was mentioned in SO answers, I know that I can configure smart-card login.)

Or where do I see the `login-configurations` in Windows 8?